# ES2015 Template Strings not parsing

Tags: javascript, meteor, ecmascript-6, template-strings

I'm attempting to begin using ES6/ES2015 features in my development and am attempting to use template strings in place of concatenation.

I have a file called `meteor.jsx` which contains the following code.

```
getLocation(lat,lon){
    return Meteor.http.call('GET','http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=${ lat },${ lon }&sensor=true&callback=zipmap')
}
```

If I call this with actual coordinates

```
Meteor.call('getLocation','37.3175','-122.0419',function(e,r){}
```

It doesn't convert `lat` or `lon` to strings, it just prints '${lat}' and '${lon}' in the return string. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Template strings should be enclosed by back-ticks ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings#Description)):

```
`http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=${ lat },${ lon }&sensor=true&callback=zipmap`
```

Comment: This is the answer, just a simple oversight on my part. Thanks for being a second pair of eyes.